# Allow sorting /admin/users/###/post-comments by deletion date

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools

I was recently trying to handle a "possible vandalism: comment deletions" auto-flag, and went to the `/admin/users/###/post-comments` page of the user in question. This was ultimately frustrating, as I didn't have any good way to see *which* comments were being deleted without clicking through all the links in the flag.

To fix this, can we add a way to sort that page by comment deletion date? It'd be okay with me if this was only available on the deleted tab, or it could be available on all pages and order the undeleted comments at the end.

Thoughts?